# Select the last document from mongo collection in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I want the latest document in the query. Below I'm getting those documents whose name is coming from the variable 'personalFullName, then sorting them by a field called 'RecordID' (this field has higher numbers as later date entries), then grab the last one. I want the latest (the one with the largest RecordID number) entry in this query:

```
Programs.find({ FullName: personalFullName }, { sort: { RecordID: 1 }, limit: 1}).fetch().pop();
```

I'm getting an error that it's exceeding the call stack size.

Comment: Does: Programs.findOne({ FullName: personalFullName }, { sort: { RecordID: -1}}) work for you?

Comment: I can't use findOne because the query may return more than one document with that name.

Comment: @ŁukaszKapica You did solve a problem for me. Although the problem with the stack size was a problem in my code that was unrelated to my question, and using 'find()' did find the right document, when performing an update I had to use 'findOne' to find the document even though there were multiple documents with the same name it had to sort. I was under the impression that by using findOne() it would first stop at the first document it finds and THEN sort them. It looks like I works the opposite.

Comment: Once you included the limit filter I'm trying to wrap my head around why findOne or pop was necessary.

Comment: I'm performing a Collection.update({}) right after the findOne() operation. Although I have a limit filter of 1, because I need to do an update by _id, I did: Collection.update({ _id: foo._id}, {$set: object}), and "foo._id" is object notation, so foo needs to be an object. findOne() returns the document itself (an object), but find() returns a cursor so the update fails. I also needed to update the second to last document in the sort with a limit of 2. In that case it looks like I need to use find({...}).fetch().pop() because pop() with take the last document (object) off the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using the `meteorhacks:aggregate` package then you could always publish the item(s) you want using the mongo aggregate pipeline, perhaps something like this (code is coffeescript):

```
Meteor.publish 'latestPrograms', (personalFullName)->
    return unless personalFullName?
    check personalFullName, String
    pipeline = [
        {$match:{'Fullname': personalFullName}}         
        {$sort: {'RecordID': 1}}
        {$group:{'_id':{Fullname: '$Fullname'}, RecordID:{$last:'$RecordID'}}}
        {$limit:1}
    ]
    @added 'latestPrograms', Random.id(), item for item in programs.aggregate pipeline
    @ready()
```

You can then grab the data by subscribing to the `latestPrograms` pseudo collection. Here is an example using a iron router route:

```
Router.route '/home', 
    name: 'home'
    template:'homepage'
    waitOn:->
        Meteor.subscribe 'latestPrograms', personalFullName
    data:->
        {latestPrograms: latestPrograms.find()}
```